# cURL not working on RightNow/Oracle Service Cloud customer portal

Tags: php, curl, crm, rightnow-crm, oracle-service-cloud

I have a small php script that I'm using to test if cURL is installed and functioning. This works in our Oracle Service Cloud sandbox environment (websitename.rightnowdemo.com), it displays the google.com at the top of the page and below, it prints the result of the test function ("cURL is installed on this server"). The same code in our dev (websitename.custhelp.com) environment, however, does not work. It only prints the "cURL is installed" message and that is all. Is there a configuration setting that needs to be set in our new environment? How can I get cURL fully functioning?

code:

```
<rn:meta title="cURL Example" template="agent.php" clickstream=""/>

<?php
load_curl();
$curlURL = "www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init($curlURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);

?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php

// Script to test if the CURL extension is installed on this server

// Define function to test
function _is_curl_installed() {
    if  (in_array  ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Ouput text to user based on test
if (_is_curl_installed()) {
  echo "cURL is <span style=\"color:#4fa361;\">installed</span> on this server";
} else {
  echo "cURL is <span style=\"color:#dc4f49\">not installed</span> on this server";
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why even bother making a curl call just to check if curl is installed?  Why are you not using `http://www.google.com` as URL?

Comment: We've tried every combination for the URL, the URL in the code above is just the last one that was tried and works on our sandbox site. We noticed problems after migrating some files from one environment to the next. Scripts using cURL that worked fine in one sandbox didn't work in dev. The cURL call was just additional means by someone here to make sure the library was available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of OSvC are you using in production (*.custhelp.com)?  More than likely, your versions are different between your demo and production environments.  It's best to develop on a true test site that is a clone of your production since the rightnowdemo environment is not in sync with your site.  Please include your production OSvC version here as you may need to use the older `dl()` method to load curl into your script.

Another issue might be that you're trying to implement your load_curl() method in a view file, which is generally a bad idea.  You should be doing that from a controller or a model.  You might be running into a namespacing issue introduced in CP3, where namespaces are enforced.  Check for `curl_init` at the root namespace instead of your CP namespace(s).

```
if (!function_exists("\curl_init"))
{
    \load_curl();
}
```

With all that said, if you are getting a message that curl is installed, then it should be loading curl properly.  More than likely, google.com is rejecting the request from the production server using curl for any number of reasons.  You can use the following to check for a curl error:

```
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
```

Comment: Hi Scott thanks for the response. We are using the August 2015 (build 141) version of OSvC. You're right, this code is being used in a view. What are the odds that it's a namespacing issue, but the message of cURL being installed is still displayed? Because I believe your second suggestion to be correct, the check for curl errors you suggest produces an error "call to undefined function curl_strerror" so maybe the namespace is interfering with cURL loading correctly.

Comment: try using the `function_exists("\curl_init")` check rather than your extension check.  The loaded extension in PHP doesn't necessarily mean that the function is exposed at the application layer.  Try removing curl_strerror just to see if errno does product a result.

Comment: yes it does, error 7 which is "Failed to connect() to host or proxy"

Comment: Are you on the PS or PC Pods?  If so, then Oracle hosting will have to open the firewall for you.  What happens when you swap out google.com with oracle.com?

Comment: We reached out to Oracle and got it straightened out. Thanks again Scott!